# logical deduction

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

My problem goes like this: Show that whenever $\Sigma\vDash\tau$, then there exists a deduction from $\Sigma$, the last component of which is $\tau$.

I have tried to go ''backward'' starting from $\tau$ to a tautology or an element in $\Sigma$ making a deduction from the end to beginning, but it is hard to trace.. I don't know how to attack this problem other than that way.. How should I attack this problem?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what you have already tried to solve it; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Comment: This is not an easy problem! Is this for propositional logic or full first-order logic?  And, to follow up on the previous comment: what have you learned about logic so far? Some context would really help, especially with such a relatively big question.

Comment: @Bram28 This problem comes from the end of propositional logic chapter. Hope this helps..

Comment: @Kkkk OK, well, that's a good bit easier than for full first-order logic. In fact, this result is called the Completeness Theorem: it took many years for it to be proven for full first-order logic and it took Kurt Godel, one of (maybe the!) greatest logicians, to prove it first. For propositional logic it is a good bit easier .. but still far from easy. I am surprised that the book would simply throw it out there, without any further hints, strategies, or other context. Are there a bunch of other problems that lead up to it?

Comment: @Bram28 There is a one problem that might be useful but i'm not sure: Let $<\alpha_0,...,\alpha_n>$ be a deduction from a set $\Sigma$ of wffs. Show that $\Sigma\vDash\alpha_k$ for each $k\leq n$. Suggestion: strong induction

Comment: @Kkkk Interestingly, that problem is effectively the converse of the Completeness Theorem, and this result is called the Soundness Theorem. Basically, Soundness is that if there is a deduction of $\alpha$ from $\Gamma$, then $\alpha$ is a logical consequence of $\Gamma$. Whereas Completeness is that if $\alpha$ is a logical consequence of $\Gamma$, then there is a deduction of $\alpha$ from $\Gamma$. Soundness is a lot easier to prove (you indeed use simple induction) than Completeness, but unfortunately proving Soundness does not help help you in proving Completeness.

Comment: @Bram28 I see. Thank you for your comments!